# What happens when restart.txt is not present in the tmp folder for Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to figure out if the absence of the restart.txt file in the tmp folder of a Rails app can cause any kind of memory leakage or infinite loops.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, that file is only present to have its timestamp checked via this simplified algorithm each time a request comes in:

1. Is there a `tmp/restart.txt`?
2. If so, is its last-updated timestamp newer than any passenger instance?
3. If so, kill the passenger instance and start a new one.

Not having a `tmp/restart.txt` file won't have any negative side effects.

Comment: Thanks Gareth! Older versions of Passenger delete the restart.txt file once it restarts. So yes, it couldn't possibly cause issues.